# Fetch recently created AD users in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-graph, azure-ad

I'm creating a scheduler Power Automate flow that will run daily and fetch the recently created in the Azure AD.
The solution provided online is using MS Graph API and using `/users` endpoint but to use it few permissions are required which can be granted by admin consent only to the App Registration.
I don't have admin rights and it's quite difficult to get permission on the client environment.

Is there any other way to get the Azure AD accounts from flow? Also, The endpoint is getting called from Graph Explorer using delegate permissions so can I use my sign-in credentials to authenticate the API and use it for getting the data from flow?

Comment: You need to tell the client they need to consent to the app registration or else they don't get the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [**Send an HTTP request** preview action in the **Office 365 Groups** connector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365groups/#send-an-http-request-(preview)). You do not need to consent any permission requests in your tenant to use this action. Users is one of the resources you can access with it.

[image: Send an HTTP request action]

Comment: It worked and yes I can apply the filter in the URI part. Although, it takes some error finding as it doesn't provide any detailed errors. Like to select the user properties we need to put `/` in the query like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=displayName,createdDateTime` to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help